# Timer (Alarmmanger) starts immediately at 12AM - 12:59AM (00:00 - 00:59)

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, timepicker

my application is designed to start a service at a specific time.

I use a **timePicker** to receive the time

```
 time.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = min;
        }
    });
```

You can press a button to activate the **alarmmanager**. The Intent should then start at this time.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int _hour = hour;
            int tmpHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int tmpMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            // Alarm is today?
            if (hour > tmpHour || (tmpHour == hour && tmpMinute < minute)){

                tmpHour *= 60;
                _hour *= 60;
            }
            **// Add 24Hours to get difference.
            else {

                tmpHour *= 60;
                _hour *= (_hour + 24) * 60;
            }**
            int minutesToAdd = (_hour + minute) - (tmpHour + tmpMinute);
            Log.d("AlarmExample", "Need to add " + minutesToAdd + " minutes");
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);


            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

...

```
//alarmmanager

            AlarmManager amanag = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            amanag .set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

I have a problem here :
When you pick a time between 12:00 AM and 12:59 AM,  **_hour *= (_hour + 24) * 60;** makes the alarm start immediately when you touch the button.

I tried to change it to  _hour = (_hour + 24) * 60;* but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea how to make this reliable?

Sincerly,
Wolfen

Comment: This can be simplified, see here : http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);     

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);               
    Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();  
//time 12.19AM
    timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19);
    timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);      


 alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

i used onAlermReciver which implement Broadcast reciver to set it to intent , then alarm went off call to OnAlermReciver, it works for me
you can use

```
 alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Comment: Hi Udaya, thanks for your answer. So I don't have to calculate the milliseconds myself? I just set my  my calendar to  this and it will activate my intent at any time? What happens if I set my Time to 10AM and the actual time is 11AM?

Comment: Calender object set time for alarm manager, it activate to the real time of the device, no need to calculate timestamp, if alarm set 10AM and actual time 11Am then it activate to next day 10AM

Comment: Unfortunately this starts the alarm immediately, too.

Comment: //check for next day
     if (calNew.getTimeInMillis() < calNow.getTimeInMillis()) {
      calNew.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
      Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf("next day!"),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }  solved my problem